# storing a id under another id using nodejs with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am developing a website similar to e-commerce which has its backend on nodejs and i want to ask if user whose is already signed up and comes to the site and login with a username and password then all the other information likewise what he/she purchased can be stored under the same login id means the id of the product purchased by the user is stored in the db under same the login id and i am using mongodb for all the database work,for eg- a user mayank logged in having id defined  by the db suppouse 12 and the product id is 15a so in the db a object should be created having the login id of the user and the product id of the product purchased by him and whenever he purchases a new product from a different section will also be added under the same login id i.e either altogether a new object with previous product information can be created or the product id of the new product can be updated in the already created login id,so suggest a way for this work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make new Collection call `Orders`,
it will contain all the details of that order..!
one document of orders collections can be like:

```
{ 
 "orderId" : "",
 "createdDate" :"",
 "status" : "",
 "paymentDetails" : [],
 "items" : [],
 "userDetails":{
   "name" : "",
   "address":"",
   "contactNo" : ""  
  }
}
```

You can add more fields accordingly..!

Comment: thankz for the reply ,can `you plz suggest the js file for this also.